# k8s-ingress issue when accessing multiple services

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress

I created ingress.yaml file to access the backend service using /api path and It can be accessed using "app.com/api" and "app.com//api". what can I do to avoid accessing it using "app.com//api".

This is my ingress.yaml file and you can get a idea of what I did so far.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-dev-ingress
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: acme-issuer
spec:
  ingressClassName: public
  rules:
  - host: "test-app.xyz"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        path: /api(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-dev-api-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

In the updated ingress.yaml file, I've changed the "pathType" value to "Prefix" instead of "ImplementationSpecific". This change ensures that only a single slash ("/") is considered as the path separator

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-dev-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: acme-issuer
spec:
  ingressClassName: public
  rules:
    - host: "test-app.xyz"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: test-dev-api-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```